Unable to update educational access rights
I downloaded it for training, but my access to training has expired, so I'm trying to update it, but it doesn't go beyond the maximum number of verification attempts. How can I resolve it?
I downloaded it for training, but my access to training has expired, so I'm trying to update it, but it doesn't go beyond the maximum number of verification attempts. How can I resolve it?!!

Can you be more specific about which training ?
